# Clean architecture/MVP: Using different repositories for different models. Is it okay?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, architecture, mvp

**The scenario:** In my application, I have different types of models from different data sources that my presenter needs, eg UserState and Tasks. I have created two seperate repositories for both of these models namely, UserStateRepository and TaskRepository.

Both of these are injected into the TaskPresenter to show tasks and user specific info based on data from both the repositories.

In fact this is just one scenario. My app has many such models, eg Dictionary, Resources, etc. Almost every presenter for a view needs two repositories injected: UserStateRepository and the "MetaInformation"Repository. Hence I end up with at least 7 different repositories.

**PS:** I use Dagger2 to inject these repositories, but only the user state repository is an application level singelton whereas other repositories generally have activity level scope. This is because I need to refresh the cache of other activity scoped repositories everytime a new instance of an activity is created but the userstate must persist.

**The question:** Does this architecture actually make sense or is there a better solution? Also how about handling different lifecycles of these repositories

Comment: Generally speaking, Yes. It makes sense to have separated repositories for different data sources. Ask yourself if there is a "hidden dependency" between some of them, ex: You always need data from rep1 to query rep2, In that case, consider creating another layer that combines the related repositories into a single application repository for easier access and cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically speaking yes, it's a good idea to have one repository per entity.

But there may be a case when you don't need it. For instance, you have an entity User which has Address entity in it. It may be the case when you do not need to work with Address as a separated entity, instead, you can get Address as a part of the User entity. So, it's sufficient to have a repository for the User but not for Address in this particular case.